# SUM Data group by date

Tags: php, report, sum

i want sum data group by date

**Example data**

```
{"reqtime":"Monday, July 30, 2012 08:55:45","user_id":"9704"},
{"reqtime":"Tuesday, September 4, 2012 11:07:11","user_id":"9717"},
{"reqtime":"Thursday, September 13, 2012 07:41:41","user_id":"9720"},
{"reqtime":"Friday, October 12, 2012 10:20:19","user_id":"9731"},
{"reqtime":"Friday, October 19, 2012 10:20:14","user_id":"9726"},
{"reqtime":"Monday, November 26, 2012 18:42:00","user_id":"9701"}
{"reqtime":"Thursday, December 6, 2012 11:33:52","user_id":"9728"},
{"reqtime":"Monday, December 10, 2012 02:55:53","user_id":"10282"},
{"reqtime":"Monday, December 10, 2012 03:02:24","user_id":"10284"},
{"reqtime":"Monday, December 10, 2012 04:02:57","user_id":"10286"},
{"reqtime":"Monday, December 10, 2012 04:18:29","user_id":"9944"},
{"reqtime":"Monday, December 10, 2012 05:22:38","user_id":"10292"},
{"reqtime":"Monday, December 10, 2012 05:23:05","user_id":"10291"},
```

become like this

example :

```
dec 10 : 6 user_id /*( **sum user_id but sorting by date** )*/
```

this is my code/script not yet summing, n not yet encode to json :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `users_demoid` order by reqtime LIMIT 0 , 100";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());

// get data and store in a json array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $date=date("l, F j, Y H:i:s",$row['reqtime']);
    $orders[] = array(
        'reqtime' => $date,
        'user_id' => $row['user_id']
      );
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Update your question with the code you've tried so others can see what's wrong.

Comment: my dear newbie, what have you try so far? SO is not a place to ask for answer. U try , u got problem, people will love to help.

Comment: what you mean by sum data

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = json_decode($json_arr) ;
$arr_res=array();
$i=0;
 foreach($arr as $stdobj)
   {
      $search = $stdobj->reqtime;
      $arr_res[$i]['user_id']=$stdobj->user_id;
      foreach($arr as $stdobj2 )
      {
            if($search == $stdobj2->reqtime)
            {
              $arr_res[$i]['sum'] +=1;
             } 
      }
   $i++
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your sample data is actually a JSON array. We'll call it `$json_data` for our example. I'm sure you already know that you can convert this data into a PHP array using `json_decode`. We'll translate the JSON into an associative array because I happen to like them more than `StdObject`s:

```
$array_data = json_decode($json_data, TRUE);
```

That will give you an multidimensional array of your data - an array containing arrays for each record as an associative record with keys for `reqtime` and `user_id`, for example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [reqtime] => Monday, December 10, 2012 02:55:53
            [user_id] => 10282
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [reqtime] => Monday, December 10, 2012 02:55:53
            [user_id] => 10282
        )

)
```

Now we have the data in a format we can iterate over, so we'll do that. On each iteration, we'll convert the `reqtime` into a convenient format for comparison - basically just dropping off the time component. We'll then add that date as a key to a result array if it doesn't exist in that array yet, or increment the value for it if it does:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array_data as $data_record) {
  $date = date('M d', strtotime($data_record['reqtime']));
  if (isset($result[$date])) {
    $result[$date]++;
  } else {
    $result[$date] = 1;
  }
}
```

Note that the date format `M d` will only contain the month and day (e.g. "Dec 10"), but not the year, so if your data could have overlapping day-of-the-years (e.g. "Dec 10 2011" and "Dec 10 2012"), then you'll need to account for that.

Also, this will count how many records there are for each date, not how many unique users. If there's a possibility that the same user could appear in more than one record on the same date, but you only want to count the user once, you'll need extra logic for that as well.

I'll leave these two as an exercise for you, since they weren't part of the original question.

Comment: but after we decoded json and do the array can we encode again the data to json ?

Comment: Encode the result array to JSON? Just use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode).